# Can't get all ApplicationUser with duplicate foreign key from table dbo.AspNetUsers instead $ref

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, code-first

It turns that when I debbug it until the end at the controller shows all the results correctly on the backend, but when it shows the results on Postman turns that the ones who had duplicate key are not displayed.


**This is the method:**

```
public HttpActionResult getUsers (){
        var users = context.Users.ToList();
        return Ok(users);
    }
```

**This is the result:**

```
[user:{
{
"Email":...,
"EmailConfirmed":.....
...
"ForeignKeyColumn": 123
},
user1:{
{
"$ref": "6"
}}]
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: The desire output is the two users with duplicate foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments, I found the answer by my own.
The problem was on the WEB API json formatter, I had this code:

```
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;<br/>
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;<br/>
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Then I changed for this and it works perfectly!!!

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;<br/>
            json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();<br/>
            json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;<br/>
```

I hope this helps somebody in future!